# Well how can I add custom vertical scrollbar in given layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollbar

Well, I am new android, have to design this page

http://cubixshade.com/images/list.jpg

what should i use ? tablelayout will be best for it ? relative layout ? which controller can be used along with it ?

and how scroll bar works in android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the top level layout a ScrollView.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 </ScrollView>
```